# Drawing error in DataGridView, when modifying DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have a WinForms program, in which I have a `DataGridView`. For that I have a `DataSource` in the shape of a `BindingList<CustomObject>`.

The source is set when the program is initiated, like this:

```
dgvExample.DataSource = myBindingList;
```

The `DataGridView` is only edited programmatically, using functions for **Adding** and **Removing** items from `myDataSource`. The "Remove" function is called when clicking the small 'x' in the left-most column.

The odd thing is, that when I remove the top row, using the Remove function, it kinda draws the two rows on top of each others, as it can be seen in the images. What the duck is going on?

**Before removing a the top row:**

[image: Before removing a row]

**After removing the top row:**

[image: After removing a row]

**The functions used for the different steps, can be seen below:**

**DataGridView_Click()**

```
private void dgvExample_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        RemoveItem(e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

**AddItem()**

```
public void AddItem(string description, decimal value)
{
    // Create custom object and set values
    CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
    obj.Description = description;
    obj.Value = value;

    // Add object to BindingList
    myBindingList.Add(obj);
}
```

**RemoveItem()**

```
public void RemoveItem(int i) 
{
   // Removes rows with index i 
   myBindingList.RemoveAt(i)
}
```

Comment: Is it an absolutely standard DataGridView or is a control inheriting from DataGridView that has been modified in some way?

Comment: I think it's some drawing error, as if the second row is repainted in the first without erasing the first. Is there some repaint / redraw function for the datagridview?

Comment: Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 help?

Comment: I have tried both `myBindingList.ResetBindings()`, `dgvExample.Refresh()` and `dgvExample.Invalidate()` but neither helped.